# postgres deadlock without explicit locking

Tags: postgresql, transactions, database-deadlocks

I use PostgreSQL 9.2, and I do not use explicit locking anywhere, neither `LOCK` statement nor `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. However, recently I got `ERROR: 40P01: deadlock detected`. The query where deadlock was detected is wrapped in transaction block though. Anyway, how comes it?

Comment: Can you show cut down queries/schema for where your deadlocks are occuring? Do you have hash-indexes in use within your transactions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need any explicit `LOCK` to go into a deadlock. Here's a very simple demo from scratch with only INSERTs:

```
create table a(i int primary key);
create table b(i int primary key);
```

Session #1 does:

```
begin;
insert into a values(1);
```

Then session #2 does:

```
begin;
insert into b values(1);
insert into a values(1);
-- here it goes into waiting for session #1 to finish its transaction
```

Then session #1 does:

```
insert into b values(1);
```

And then the deadlock occurs:

> ERROR:  deadlock detected
>   DETAIL:  Process 9571 waits for ShareLock on
>   transaction 4150; blocked by process 9501.
>   Process 9501 waits for
>   ShareLock on transaction 4149; blocked by process 9571.
>    HINT:  See
>   server log for query details.

The same could happen with simple UPDATEs or a combination of UPDATEs and INSERTs.
These operations take implicit locks, and if they happen in different sessions in different orders, they may deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect hash indexes first.

- Switch any `hash`-indexes you have to `B-tree`
- Use [`Serializable`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) isolation level if it seems appropriate.

Comment: I do not have any hash indexes, anyway how can they be the reason?

Comment: Possible since [hash-bucket-level locks are used for read/write access](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/locking-indexes.html) as part of their implementation.